# How to store Google Maps DrawingManager Rectangle overlay in PostgreSQL Postgis GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY, 4326)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, google-maps, map-drawing

What is the correct way to store a Google Maps DrawingManager rectangle overlay? The API basically provides me with NE & SW lat/long coordinates. Should I use BOX()? Is it possible to create a BOX() from a GeoJSON object?

Answer (score 1):

At some point you'll have to convert from Google native overlays to WKT. You can either do it in your frontend, using for example [Wicket.js](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket) or in your backend, using postgis's [ST_FromGeoJson](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html). Keep in mind that there's no geoJSON spec for rectangles. They're just polygons.

If you use [Wicket.js](https://github.com/arthur-e/Wicket) you will be able to ingest a WKT BOX to generate a  [google.maps.Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Rectangle)

```
var wicketReader = new Wkt.Wkt();
var rect=wicketReader.read( 'BOX(-71 -21,-70 -20)').toObject();
rect instanceof google.maps.Rectangle;
> true
```

However, for the sake of consistency, when you export it as WKT, you'll get the equivalent polygon:

```
var wicketReader = new Wkt.Wkt();
var newRectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle(
    {bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(-21,-71), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(-20,-70)
    )}
);
wicketReader.fromObject(newRectangle).toString();
> "POLYGON((-71 -20,-70 -20,-70 -21,-71 -21,-71 -20))"
```

This is because you could also want to export it as geoJSON and it wouldn't make sense to output a different object

```
wicketReader.fromObject(newRectangle).toJson();
> {type:"Polygon", coordinates:[
    [
      [-71,-20],
      [-70,-20],
      [-70,-21],
      [-71,-21],
      [-71,-20]
    ]
 ]}
```

So, you see, this wont work to export your Rectangles to boxes. But nothing stops you from extending the google.maps.Rectangle class

```
google.maps.Rectangle.prototype.toBox = function () {
    var bounds = this.getBounds();
    var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
    return ['BOX(', SW.lng(), ' ', SW.lat(), ' , ', NE.lng(), ' ', NE.lat(), ')'].join('');
};
```

So you can do:

```
newRectangle.toBox();
> "BOX(-71 -21,-70 -20)"
```

Keep in mind that in PostGIS, the Box2D type is a geometry by itself, as opposed to WKT that is just text. This means BOX2D is treated differently. For example:

```
INSERT INTO myrectangles (the_geom) values (box2d('BOX(-71 -21,-70 -20)');
```

Stores a geometry. whereas

```
SELECT box2d(the_geom) from myrectangles;
```

Yields a string.

If you used `ST_GeomFromText` on a BOX string, it would result in an error.

If you used `ST_AsText` in a BOX geometry, it would yield the equivalent polygon.

This means you'll have to adapt your logic to apply the `Box2D` function both when storing and retrieving a box geometry.

Disclaimer: I'm a humble contributor to Wicket.